# Should I replace a GFI in my kitchen that will not reset?

Tags: electrical, gfci, appliances

I have three wall plugs fed into a 15A wall GFI. One of the outlets has a refrigerator with a two pronged plug.  When plugging in a toaster oven and countertop grill the circuit tripped and will not reset.

Is it safe to replace the GFI?

Comment: Is the fridge plugged into a GFI? That can be a bad thing because I know people who have lost their entire contents in their freezer while on vacation because a storm tripped the GFI. So I rewired my freezer on a separate line.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you can't reset the GFI even when nothing is plugged into it: Yes, they can wear out and may need to be replaced. Obviously, turn off the power at the circuit breaker before removing this one and installing the replacement.

If you can reset it with nothing plugged in, then the problem is probably the appliance rather than the GFI. Get it repaired or get a replacement.